# Receiving -2 Reputation in several answers

Tags: support, reputation

i wonder why i get -2 Reputation in several answers..
This is an example, overall i got -2 Reputation
[Angular HttpClient: Post method does not set parameter correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179411/angular-httpclient-post-method-does-not-set-parameter-correctly/)

Another example
[axios does not work with while fetch does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851944/axios-does-not-work-with-while-fetch-does/)

I wonder why i should take my time to answer if the result is negative reputation.
There is no indicator in the Question Post that i received negative Reputation but the Dashboard  tells me that i got -2 Reputation

Comment: -2 comes from a down vote, I guess. In the linked answer you have 2 upvotes and 1 downvote. So your rep change is 2 * 10 - 2 = +18.

Comment: The unserious use of the voting feature is really annoying if you want to build up reputation :(

Thank you for the quick answer!
So there is nothing i can do against it?

Comment: Because that's how reputation works. From MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Comment: If you're getting downvotes on many answers (more than two) there's a chance you're being targeted, and then the downvotes will get automatically reverted within a day. Still, nothing you can or need to do.

Comment: No, not really. If someone finds that your answer is "not useful" they can give it a downvote. Most times it means that "the are room for improvements" (and you can try to improve your answer). At other times it's nearly impossible to understand what caused the down vote.

Comment: Both linked questions have given you +18 rep. That's 36 total rep gain. That's not bad. We all get down votes from time to time. BTW: If you post answer and it only gets down votes, you can delete the answer and get your rep back.

Comment: You can vote up or down. So do other users. It's how the site works. Votes are very important, downvotes as important as upvotes.

Comment: If you're getting this upset about a couple of downvotes, that might be the right call. Voting and downvotes are an essential part of Stack Overflow. If you're going to participate here, you need to be able to handle them.

Comment: lol..
so in result i can get into your profile and downvote all your stuff because i am upset how you comment..
great system

Comment: @xzesstence There are provisions in place to deal with serial and targeted voting.

Comment: as people said before, its the right of any user to downvote without reason !?
this is exactly the behaviour and the reason why i asked the question

Comment: If you want to improve your posts, you should start by capitalizing all i -> I.  Then remove all useless punctuation (`..`). Make sure each sentence starts with a capital letter. Stop using stack snippets for code that can't be executed. Remove linebreaks in the middle of sentences.

Comment: Everybody can vote: Upvoting requires 15 rep. Downvoting 125 rep. Explaining votes is not only not required, but actively discouraged.

Comment: See [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/7296893). Explanations are not required, and you certainly don't have the right to get an explanation.

Comment: *as people said before, its the right of any user to downvote without reason !?* Correct. [Explaining votes is discouraged.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin). The only thing that is forbidden is targeted voting on a user.

Comment: "lol.. so in result i can get into your profile and downvote all your stuff ..." yes - and it happens but...  it will be detected and I'll get all the rep back and you could be suspended... BTW: Are you aware that **down votes ain't free** ? A down vote costs the down voter -1 in rep.

Comment: As nobody has mentioned it so far (unless I missed it), I wanted to point out that downvotes on meta don't change your reputation (or cost reputation), as a result of this (assumedly) people tend to be a little more liberal with their use of downvotes. So don't take it too personally. Besides, it would be a shame to lose someone who is actively trying to add useful content to the site :)

Comment: You are being targeted by a single user, he's got enough experience to limit his voting so these downvotes are not detected by the machine.  Targeted voting is evil and we don't put up with that.  Flag one of your posts for moderator attention and ask them to look at your profile.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> i wonder why i get -2 Reputation in several answers..

1. People have the right to down-vote answers without specifying a reason
2. If this is happening to multiple answers then you need to consider the following:

   - Your answer is actually down-vote worthy: Go through your answers which received down-votes and see how you can improve them
   - Alternatively, you are being targeted for whatever reason and the voting correction script will most likely resolve this, if for whatever reason it doesn't, you can flag your answer with a custom mod flag and request they look into it

> I wonder why i should take my time to answer if the result is negative reputation.

There is no compulsion in regards to answering questions, it is a choice, more specifically, it's *your* choice. Down-votes are a part and parcel of the SE network and the quicker you get used to the fact that your rep is just a number, the better your experience will become.

> There is no indicator in the Question Post that i received negative Reputation but the Dashboard tells me that i got -2 Reputation

If you have 1000+ rep, clicking on the number between the up-vote and down-vote arrow will show you the breakdown of the voting on your question / answer.

Comment: I believe it is however I was under the impression that you could view the rep breakdown of your own Q&As without the need of that privilege.

Comment: You get this privilege once you reach 1000 reputation points https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user

Answer (score 3):

The -2 is just a rep "tick" that pops up below the "trophy" icon whenever you reputation changes. On answers, you get +10 for up-votes and -2 for down votes.

In both the linked cases you have gotten 2 up-votes and 1 down-vote. So you have gained 10+10-2 = 18 rep per post.

When you get 1000 rep, you'll be able to see the total amount of up and down votes on posts. On your own posts specifically, you can see all the details:

- Click on your user profile.
- Activity tab, then Reputation tab.